# Android phone as a dedicated device

Tags: android, barcode, app-startup

We want to use Android mobile for dedicated application. Can somebody suggest how can we make it happen.

Here are the requirement:

1. The phone when started, should launch our application., so the user cannot launch any other application. The application will be a 1D barcode reader.
2. The application should be live as long as the phone is up and running, user cannot close the application at all.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Manish

Comment: If you're looking for a single-use locked down device I outline some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644803/2888763

Answer (score 6):

Android after boot is complete sends a bradcast intent:

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

if you listen for this intent, you can launch a service that in turn launch your activity.
In the Activity you have to take care of the user's interactions that explicitly close the activity, like home button, back button and camera button press.

Setting your activity to be full-screen also should prevent the user to use the notification bar to interact with notification like those from market-app that can close your activity.

Finally, your activity can be killed by the system by various and uncatchable reasons: in those cases, the service that first launched your Activity comes in handy, as it can periodically monitor the general state of the application and relaunch components as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the new Android Enterprise solutions for your use case.

https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview

Its well documented. You can either use

- Android Management API to provision the devices and apply policies to the device which will be applied to the device using Android's Device Policy Controller (DPC) or,
- Use Google Play EMM API and develop your custom DPC

It depends upon your use-case really, but the first solution set should serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no single answer to this, but you need to work on multiple fronts.

One of these fronts is preventing user from running other applications: for this there are applications sold on Android Market that can put other apps of your choosing behind passcode.

You need to combine this with automatic launch, but I don't yet know how to do that.