# Soti Mobicontrol - android kiosk devices

Tags: android, mdm, kiosk, soti

I'm currently evaluating Soti Mobicontrol (v13) for the remote control of a set of android devices that must work as kiosks. 
Those devices must always have a particular app running, are single app devices, and in cases where the app crash or exits the app must be restarted or taken in foreground.

Using scripts (http://www.soti.net/mc/help/v13/en/Content/ScriptCmdSet.htm) is possible to check:

1 - which app is currently in foreground (with script *identify_activity*)

2 - start an app (*Start com.foo.app.ExampleApp*)

What it seems is not possible is to combine those scripts and let them be executed periodically to check the current device situation and correct it if necessary.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to have the ability to check which app is foreground or are you looking for a solution to always have your app in the foreground and prevent the user from doing anything else with the device?

Comment: @TrevorHalvorson the main point I want to achieve is the latter you said, but since with Soti it's not possibile (till the version 13) to have a single app lockdown (with app always in execution) I was lloking at ways to actively check the foreground app in order to take measures.

Comment: have you looked at Lock Task Mode? check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43644803/2888763

Comment: You could schedule a period file sync rule to execute some script.
That should do the trick